# Controlar la introducción de caracteres en cin ( c++ )

Tags: c++

Tengo un problema el cual es que quiero controlar la introducción de sólo números mediante cin en una variable de tipo int.

```
int  horas;
cin >> horas;
```

cuando introduzco un valor que no es un número entero como un carácter y horas vale 0 y no puedo realizar un `isdigit` para la comprobación.

Comment: Hola bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero terminar el [recorrido del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), y lo mas importante [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y te podamos ayudar de mejor manera :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si tu código tiene estas líneas:

```
int  horas;
cin >> horas;
```

Y el usuario introduce, por ejemplo, esto:

```
ABCDEF
```

Lo que sucede es que `cin` ve que no puede convertir la secuencia de entrada en un número, como es lógico. Entonces activa el flag de error y se bloquea hasta que dicho flag se resetee.

Lo más limpio es resetear el flag de error. Normalmente junto con esta acción se tiende a limpiar completamente el buffer de entrada para descartar los caracteres erróneos ya que se entiende que el usuario no ha introducido el dato que se le pedía:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max());
cin.clear();
```

La primera línea descarta todos los caracteres que se encuentren en el buffer de entrada. Si solo te interesa descartar hasta el primer salto de línea puedes configurar la llamada así:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(),'\n');
```

Por otro lado, `numeric_limits` es una plantilla (*template*) que indica los valores máximos y mínimos alcanzables por cada tipo de dato. Así:

```
std::numeric_limits<int>::max()
```

Devuelve el valor máximo alcanzable por el tipo `int`.

Por otro lado, `cin.clear()` resetea el flag de error, entre otros (que ahora mismo a tí tampoco te interesan) y permite que `cin` vuelva a funcionar con normalidad.

Por supuesto todo esto no va a funcionar si no eres capaz de detectar que se ha producido el error. Hay varias formas de verificar el error, yo te pongo una de ellas:

```
cin >> horas;
if( cin.fail() )
{
  cout << "No has introducido un numero\n";
  cin.ignore(numeric_limits<int>::max());
  cin.clear();
}
else
{
  cout << "Has introducido el numero " << horas;
}
```

Piensa que cuando tu haces esto:

```
int  horas;
cin >> horas;
```

Le estás pidiendo a `cin` que te devuelva un número... no tiene ningún sentido que intentes usar `is_digit` ya que `horas` únicamente puede almacenar números... no caracteres.

También puedes leer la entrada como una cadena de texto y verificar si lo introducido es un número... es exactamente lo mismo que hace `cin` por debajo solo que puedes tener la certeza de que `cin` lo va a hacer mejor que tu.

Comment: Muchas gracias @eferion, es evidente que si te preguntan en un programa que introduzcas horas, vas a introducir un número; Pero a mi personalmente me gusta validar la entrada de todos los datos. Por cierto ¿Si utilizo cin.clear() me borra todos los cin almacenados anteriormente? Si por ejemplo yo utilizo 2 variables para almacenar la entrada del cin en la segunda y así si yo hago un cin.clear() no perder valores anteriores válidos, ¿Esto sería efectivo?

Comment: @Sexde clear solo resetea los flags. Y si te fijas veras cin ya esta validando los datos por ti...